# checking if all the items in list occur in another list using linq

Tags: sql, linq, list, comparison

I am stuck with a problem here. I am trying to compare items in a list to another list with much more items using linq.

For example:

```
list 1: 10,15,20
list 2: 10,13,14,15,20,30,45,54,67,87
```

I should get `TRUE` if all the items in `list 1` occur in `list 2`. So the example above should return `TRUE`

Like you can see I can't use `sequenceEquals`

Any ideas?

EDIT:

list2 is actually not a list it is a column in sql thas has following values:
`<id>673</id><id>698</id><id>735</id><id>1118</id><id>1120</id><id>25353</id>`.

in linq I did the following queries thanks to Jon Skeets help:

```
var query = from e in db
            where e.taxonomy_parent_id == 722
            select e.taxonomy_item_id;
```

query is `IQueryable` of longs at this moment

```
var query2 = from e in db
             where query.Contains(e.taxonomy_item_id)
             where !lsTaxIDstring.Except(e.taxonomy_ids.Replace("<id>", "")
                                                       .Replace("</id>", "")
                                                       .Split(',').ToList())
                                 .Any()
             select e.taxonomy_item_id;
```

But now I am getting the error `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
if (!list1.Except(list2).Any())
```

That's about the simplest approach I can think of. You could explicitly create sets etc if you want:

```
HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int>(list2);
if (!list1.Any(x => set2.Contains(x)))
```

but I'd expect that to pretty much be the implementation of `Except` anyway.

Comment: Hi, I get the following `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains` If I try to use Except(). Any idea why?

Comment: @Ozkan: Ah, so you don't have lists as per your question - you have LINQ to SQL sequences? It would help if you could provide more context in your question.

Comment: Hi Jon, I updated the topic message. you can see my updated text under `EDIT:`

Comment: @Ozkan: Is there nothing you can do about the fact that your database contains XML instead of a more appropriate data format (e.g. a separate relationship table)?

Comment: This is added because of a transpose query. And ms sql 2008 is adding this automatically as Expr1 (I changed it to id)

Comment: @Ozkan: It's not really clear what you mean, to be honest. Bear in mind that we don't have all the context you have. If you could change your schema to use a normal relationship, it would make life simpler.

Comment: I know the table isn't normalised. But this is the only way. I don't have rights to change the table structures. Isn't there any way to make this query work? I don't look at performance anymore because it is already too much time i spent to this... Thanks

Comment: @Ozkan: I can't think of any simple way to represent the nastiness that would be required in SQL with a LINQ query. Options: 1) Fix the schema. (It's not just a matter of normalization - it's a matter of inappropriate data representation.) 2) Pull all the data from the database and do all the operations locally. 3) Write a stored procedure.

Comment: I think i am gonna copy it to a csv or something else. but changing the table structure is not an option, because if i remove the xml nodes, even then i need to use `Split` which will give me the same error I think

Answer (score 3):

This should be what you want:

```
!list1.Except(list2).Any()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = list1.All(i => list2.Any(i2 => i2 == i));
```